# Cucumber features test fail but single cucumber test passes facebook and twitter test

Tags: facebook, cucumber, capybara, twitter-oauth, bdd

I've created test to simulate logging in facebook and twitter to register on my app. When I run the individual cucumber test, it passes. However, when I run the entire cucumber test, it fails at the facebook and twitter logging in.

Note: the point where it fails is the 2nd time the facebook and twitter scenario is used to login. The 1st time the feature used passed.

When running cucumber features.

```
Unable to find field "email" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
./features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:13:in `/^I log in with my facebook email and password quiz$/'
./features/support/database_cleaner.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
features/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook.feature:7:in `And I log in with my facebook email and password quiz'

Unable to find field "username_or_email" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
./features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter_steps.rb:13:in `/^I log in with my twitter email and password quiz$/'
./features/support/database_cleaner.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
features/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter.feature:7:in `And I log in with my twitter email and password quiz'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook.feature:3 # Scenario: Viewing quiz entrant sign in with facebook
cucumber features/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter.feature:3 # Scenario: Viewing quiz entrant sign in with twitter
```

Running individual cucumber test

```
Using the default profile...
Feature: Entrant Sign In Quiz with facebook

  Scenario: Viewing quiz entrant sign in with facebook            # features/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook.feature:3
    Given there is a quiz entrant sign in page facebook           # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:1
    When I visit the quiz entrant microsite sign in page facebook # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:8
I, [2016-03-10T09:24:47.442080 #41761]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
I, [2016-03-10T09:24:47.443293 #41761]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
    Then I click on the social facebook login button              # features/step_definitions/microsites/photo_upload/microsites_photo_upload_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:14
I, [2016-03-10T09:24:50.419651 #41761]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
I, [2016-03-10T09:24:50.420759 #41761]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
    And I log in with my facebook email and password quiz         # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:12
    Then I complete the quiz entrant registration for facebook    # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:18
    And I can click Enter to upload a photo entry                 # features/step_definitions/microsites/photo_upload/microsites_photo_upload_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:33

1 scenario (1 passed)
6 steps (6 passed)
0m12.362s

Using the default profile...
Feature: Entrant Sign In Quiz with twitter

  Scenario: Viewing quiz entrant sign in with twitter            # features/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter.feature:3
    Given there is a quiz entrant sign in page twitter           # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter_steps.rb:1
    When I visit the quiz entrant microsite sign in page twitter # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter_steps.rb:8
I, [2016-03-10T09:39:32.581672 #41900]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
I, [2016-03-10T09:39:32.582803 #41900]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Request phase initiated.
    Then I click on the social twitter login button              # features/step_definitions/microsites/photo_upload/microsites_photo_upload_entrant_sign_in_twitter_steps.rb:14
I, [2016-03-10T09:39:36.825594 #41900]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Setup endpoint detected, running now.
I, [2016-03-10T09:39:36.829630 #41900]  INFO -- omniauth: (twitter) Callback phase initiated.
    And I log in with my twitter email and password quiz         # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter_steps.rb:12
    Then I complete the quiz entrant registration for twitter    # features/step_definitions/microsites/quiz/microsites_quiz_entrant_sign_in_twitter_steps.rb:18
    And I can click Enter to upload a photo entry                # features/step_definitions/microsites/photo_upload/microsites_photo_upload_entrant_sign_in_facebook_steps.rb:33

1 scenario (1 passed)
6 steps (6 passed)
0m14.284s
```

Comment: Look at what page is being shown when the find for email fails (dump the html, etc)-- I'm guessing some cookie isn't getting reset and it's just bypassing the login completely - also what driver are you using with Capybara?

Comment: How can I 'dump the html' ? I'm using `save_and_open_page`. However, I tried to clear the cookies, didn't work. `browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser` `browser.manage.delete_all_cookies`. I'm using firefox as the driver. `#<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x4ce1a7589361af80 browser=:firefox>`. The page shown is the facebook login page, where it's asking for email, and password.

Comment: Here is the html: `<input class="inputtext _55r1 inputtext _1kbt inputtext _1kbt" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" placeholder="Email or Phone Number" value="" autofocus="1" aria-label="Email or Phone Number" type="text">`

Comment: `puts page.html` should print the html to the screen and you can see whats actually on the page -- maybe add `sleep 5` before or something just to make sure the page has loaded

Comment: I found out the problem. The 1st time facebook is logged in when it runs the 1st scenario, it pass. But for the 2nd time, since it's already logged in. It doesn't need to log in again. How can I log out session facebook using capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a gem that can used to log out of facebook

[Capybara Facebook Macros](https://github.com/jordanrs/capybara-facebook-macros/blob/master/README.md)